# Is a locally constant function from a profinite abelian p-group constant modulo an open normal subgroup?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, topological-groups, p-adic-number-theory

Suppose $f$ is a p-adic valued function from a profinite abelian group $B$ ($Z_{p}$ or $Z_{p}^{*}$) such that for all $x$ in $B$ there is an open set $N(x)$ around $x$ such that $f$ is constant on $N(x)$. Then, my question is, for every such function does there exist an open normal subgroup $H$ such that $f$ is constant modulo $H$?

Comment: I don’t think you mean what you wrote. For a function to be constant modulo $H$, it would mean that on $\Bbb Z_p/H$ (a finite set), an associated function is constant, i.e. takes only one value.

Comment: [tag:Lubin] I meant that $f$ takes same value on any two members of $B$ that are congruent modulo $H$. Thanks!

Comment: You meant to ask whether there is a normal subgroup $H$ so small that on each coset of $H$, the function is constant. Yes, by compactness of the original group, and I’m sure that you can figure out a proof. Note that this has nothing to do with the topology of the value-space.